# Add to a list a new object each 3 positions

Tags: r, list

I'm triying to deal with a list of audio objects called `n`,class list:

```
>head(n)

[[1]]

Wave Object
        Number of Samples:      88516
        Duration (seconds):     2.01
        Samplingrate (Hertz):   44100
        Channels (Mono/Stereo): Stereo
        PCM (integer format):   TRUE
        Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16 


[[2]]

Wave Object
        Number of Samples:      88552
        Duration (seconds):     2.01
        Samplingrate (Hertz):   44100
        Channels (Mono/Stereo): Stereo
        PCM (integer format):   TRUE
        Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16
```

I want to introduce another wave element every three positions. I've seen different solutions here but no one is working. See:

```
i <- 1
while(i==i*3) {
    n[[i]] <- new_wave_element
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Nothing happens (is a stackoverflow solution)... but, e.g

```
append(n, list(x=new_wave_element), 3)
```

works fine in this case, but not in the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If x is your list of wave objects, then this should work.

```
set.seed(1)

x <- as.list(sample(1:10, 4))

l <- list()

s <- seq(from=1, by=3, length.out=length(x))

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    l[[s[i]]] <- x[[i]]
}
```

Or

```
set.seed(1)

x <- as.list(sample(1:10, 4))
s <- seq(from=1, by=3, length.out=length(x))

l2 <- vector("list", length=max(s))
l2[s] <- x
```

Comment: Just trying, I was away. It looks fine. The first is not working, or almost...the idea is good.